# concatenate lag variable and create new extended data frame in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

am new to python so the question might sound easy to experts but am trying to create a data frame in python, which will not cut the lag variable from the bottom and we will have new data frame with rows( org. data frame row + lag # ).

am trying this using "pd.concat" and shift(lag#) but no luck so far.

Ex. assume DF have 2 variable ( date and var1) then new data frame should have 3 variable (date, var1,lag_1_var1) in which "date" and "var1" column will have "NA" value at the bottom as we will be adding 1  more row (last row lag 1 of var1), so the dimension of original DF is say n*2 and new is (n +1 (as lag1))*3

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has a [shift](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) function that does this.

Comment: new_lst1=df.v1.copy();
lst1=dfv1.copy();

Day1=721;

lst1[:Day1]='nan';
Lag1=pd.DataFrame(lst1[:Day1].append ( new_lst1 ,ignore_index=True  ));